# Tensor flow: Passing bool variable while creating and evaluating graph

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I want to pass a Boolean value which can change while I am evaluating the graph. I am posting my code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

def my_model(input, is_freeze):
      trainable = tf.cond(is_freeze, lambda: tf.constant(False), 
                          lambda: tf.constant(True))   #Try 3
      #trainable = tf.cond(is_freeze, lambda: False, lambda: True) # Try 1
      #trainable = tf.logical_not(is_freeze)  # Try 2
      fc1_W = tf.get_variable('fc1_W', trainable = trainable, 
                              initializer = tf.zeros(100, 2))
      fc1 = tf.matmul(input, fc1_W)
      return fc1

tf.reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)     
is_freeze = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
my_model_graph = my_model(X, is_freeze)  # Getting error while creating model

with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      sess.run(my_optimizer, feed_dict = {is_freeze: False, X: np.zeros((50, 100))})
```

I am getting the errors as shown below:  For `#Try1`

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'name'
```

For `#Try3`:

```
TypeError: Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed.
Use if t is not None: instead of if t: to test if a tensor is defined,
and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on 
the value of a tensor.`
```

Please can somebody explain me how should I overcome this problem. And if possible, can anybody tell me where I am going wrong in all of my approaches.

Basically what I am doing is I have two models. First I train one of the models, then using the learned values of first model, I have to train the second model freezing the values of first model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you implement it by drawing all nodes into the graph but return only a part of the results to run only a part of the graph through the right path?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use `True` and `False` inside "the graph" - you need to pass them from `python` to `tensorflow`, one way to do this is with `tf.constant()`. You can try

```
def my_model(input, is_freeze):
    trainable = tf.cond(is_freeze, lambda: tf.constant(False), lambda: tf.constant(True))
```

Otherwise looks fine to me! Please provide a minimal working example if you want more detailed help!

Comment: I have tried your approach. But it is not working. I have provided full code now. Please can you check it.

Comment: Also, there seems to be no library named as `condtf` as you are showing in the example. Please can you check it.

Comment: Please can you suggest how to overcome the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are trying to embed the switch from inference / logic inside your tensorflow graph. Is not advisable to do so. Check out the new [Estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f821ce046df71f5784ed4ce7fb6b87f77d96b031/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py#L984) interface to see how you can achieve cleanly the same goal.

Comment: I have provided full code now. Should I still use `Estimator`? I will look into them, but in the meantime, can you please give a small code sample relating to my example. It will be very helpful.